# How do you select multple rows from table and put in seperate arrays?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

just wondering if anyone can help. I am trying to load data into tabs from my SQL database and was wondering if anyone knows how to load four rows of data into four different arrays. I think I am nearly there with my code but am a bit stuck.

Alternatively if anyone knows of any tutorials for loading data from a database into tabs that also loads data into each [li] it would be much appreciated.
Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT title, author, date_added FROM table ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 4");
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$array[] = $row1;
?>

<div class="tabs-c">
    <ul class="tab-c-nav">               
       <li class="tab-c-active"><a href="#tab-c-1"><?php echo $row1['title'];?></a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab-c-2"><?php echo $row2['title'];?></a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab-c-3"><?php echo $row3['title'];?></a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab-c-4"><?php echo $row4['title'];?>/a></li>
  </ul> 

  <div class="tab-c-content">               
        <div class="text-details-content-half-row">
            <div class="text-details-content-row-text-left">Written by</div>
            <div class="text-details-content-row-text-right"><?php echo $row1['author']?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-details-content-row-space"></div>
        <div class="text-details-content-half-row">
            <div class="text-details-content-row-text-left">Date Added</div>
            <div class="text-details-content-row-text-right"><?php echo $row1['date_added']?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: don't forget the closing bracket } after $array[] = $row; before ?>

Answer (score 1):

I think you mess it up a bit. The variables `$row1`, `$row2`, `$row3`, `$row4` you use are not declared anywhere. What you you need is a `while` loop to populate your `$array` as follows:

`$array[] = $row;`

Then you can have access in the different rows like this:

`echo $array[0]['title'];`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$array[] = $row1;
```

With:

```
$array[] = $row;
```

And then:

```
<ul class="tab-c-nav">               
   <li class="tab-c-active"><a href="#tab-c-1"><?php echo $array[0]['title'];?></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-c-2"><?php echo $array[1]['title'];?></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-c-3"><?php echo $array[2]['title'];?></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-c-4"><?php echo $array[3]['title'];?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
$array[] = $row1;
```

With this

```
$array[] = $row;
```

It's simple way to achieve that create reach row of table as array.

Then we can traverse into each array using their index like $array[0]['title']

Comment: nice try, but should be the other way around. edit your question and try explaining a bit to

Comment: Do you want more explanation?

Comment: not me, but it's better to explain your answer then to just burst it out. and you still have it the other way around